# How to know if it is on the left or on the right after doing a function that returns Either?

Tags: haskell, either

I'm new to Haskell and I want to do a function that returns an exit if it's left but I don't know how to do it.H
ere is my function which returns either :

````
getOpts :: Conf->[String]-> Either String Conf
getOpts Help _ = Right Help
getOpts c@Conf{} ("--start":x:xs) = readPos x >>= (\x-> getOpts c{start = x} xs)
getOpts c@Conf{} ("--lines":x:xs) = 
    readPos x >>= (\x-> getOpts c{Main.lines = x} xs)
getOpts c@Conf{} ("--window":x:xs) = 
    readPos x >>= (\x-> getOpts c{window = x} xs)
getOpts c@Conf{} ("--move":x:xs) = readPos x >>= (\x-> getOpts c{move = x} xs)
getOpts c@Conf{} ("--rules":x:xs) = 
    readMPos x >>= (\x-> getOpts c{rules = x} xs)
getOpts c []  = Right c 
getOpts _ _ = Left "Invalid Parameter!"```
````

Comment: [**`isLeft`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:isLeft)?

Comment: can I do it like this?
check :: Either a b -> IO()
check a = if isleft a == true then exiwith 42

Comment: Use pattern matching e.g. `check (Left x) = exitWith ... ; check (Right y) = ....`. In this way you not only know if it's a left or right value, but you also get access to which value (`x` and `y` in my example).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways:

If you want to handle the result explicitly, you could pattern match on the `Either` constructors:

```
foo :: Either a b -> c
foo (Left a) = <some function from (a -> c)>
foo (Right b) = <some function from (b -> c)>
```

You could use `isLeft` and `isRight` from `Data.Either` if you have some conditions that you want to handle depending on the previous result. It seems like you're working with command-line arguments, so you're probably in the IO monad. There are functions like `fromLeft` and `fromRight`, which take default values if their pattern matches fail, otherwise they unwrap the matching constructor. This looks like `fromLeft :: a -> Either a b -> a`, where the `a` you provide will be returned if it's a `Right` value. You could use these like:

```
whenIsLeft :: (a -> IO ()) -> Either a b -> IO ()
whenIsLeft f e = if isLeft e then (applyToLeft f e) else pure ()
  where applyToLeft func (Left x) = func x

explodeIfRight :: Either a b -> a
explodeIfRight = fromLeft (error "KABOOM")

whichHand :: Either a b -> String
whichHand e = if isLeft e then "Left!!!" else "Right :DDD"
```

For `whenIsLeft`, `f` could be something like `\err -> print err >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)`. Keep in mind that there's a similar-sounding function for `Maybe`: `fromJust`, which will throw an error by default if the pattern match fails.

You could also express this with pattern matching to avoid the `if isLeft then fromLeft...`:

```
whenIsLeft' :: (a -> IO ()) -> Either a b -> IO ()
whenIsLeft' f (Left e) = f e
whenIsLeft' _ (Right _) = pure ()
```

Finally, there's a really handy combinator function in the prelude called `either`, which takes two functions, one for each possible "path".

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
either errFunc successFunc leftOrRight = 
  case leftOrRight of
    Left e -> errFunc e
    Right x -> successFunc x
```

Both functions need to return the same type, so you can use this as a way to handle your errors and get back on track, or exit if the error is unrecoverable.

```
exitIfLeft :: Either a b -> IO ()
exitIfLeft = either (\err -> print err >> exitWith (ExitFailure 1)) (pure . const ())
```

In general, `Either` forms a monad that will short circuit if a chain of `Either`-returning functions fails, so you don't usually need to pattern match until the very end.

For instance, if you had 3 functions, any of which could fail with an error message:

```
f :: w -> Either String x
g :: x -> Either String y
h :: y -> Either String z
```

Then you could just chain (compose) them together like

```
fgh :: w -> Either String z
fgh w = f w >>= g >>= h
```

and only have to check the result at the end.

```
unlessZ :: w -> String
unlessZ w = case (f w >>= g >>= h) of
  Left e ...
  -- the ideal use case for `either`
```

The monad instance abstracts away all the pattern matching/error checking for you. If you have some function that you only want to apply to one branch, you can use `left` and `right` from Control.Arrow, or use the `Functor` instance for `Either` to map that function inside the container if the value is inside a `Right` constructor.

In *general* general, your control flow in Haskell is decided by pattern matching on different data constructors. You can build entire systems of handlers by just assigning a function to each constructor of a data type.